How would an observer view the apparent motion of planets in the Neo-Tychonain model?
When observing the motion of bodies in the solar system, the common observer viewpoint is that situated on Earth. However, when viewing the apparent motion of Earth from Mars in a given system, for example, the Heliocentric model, the dynamics seen are different compared to when looking from Earth. So, looking at the Neo-Tychonian system given by L. Popov [1] [2], how would an observer view the apparent motion of Earth and the Sun from Mars, compared to viewing the apparent motion of Mars and the Sun in the same given system?
[1] L. Popov, “Newtonian–Machian analysis of the neo-Tychonian model of planetary
motions,” European Journal of Physics, vol. 34, no. 2, pp. 383–391, Jan. 2013,
doi: https://doi.org/10.1088/0143-0807/34/2/383.
[2] https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6045

Apologies, a new link has been added [2]


The animation on the left shows the apparent motion of Earth (blue) and the Sun (yellow) as seen from Mars (red). The animation on the right shows the apparent motion of the Sun and Mars from a geocentric point of view. The represented time span of the animation is approximately 1.5 Earth years. and the red and blue loci span about 4 years. The ratio of the orbit radii and orbital periods are approximately to scale. The size of the Sun and the planets relative the orbit radii is much greater than in reality for visibility. In the heliocentric system the elliptical orbits are approximated as being circular and then transformed to the epicyclic orbits seen in the animation. The observer in the centre of each system is 'hovering' above the North pole of the respective planets and always facing a given distant star, rather than rotating with the planet. Note how the planets appear to orbit clockwise around the Sun in these systems, despite orbiting in the the opposite direction in the heliocentric system and relative to the distant stars.
The GeoGebra construction including a 3D representation is here.
